# Wamp, 500 Internal Server Error when IndexIgnore is enabled in .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp, wampserver, zen-cart

I managed to isolate the error to the following.

The wamp server gives an Internal Server Error when the code as follows

```
IndexIgnore */*
```

It works fine when I comment this line as follows

```
#IndexIgnore */*
```

I need to understand the reason for this error and how to solve this in wamp.

Comment: Do you have `autoindex_module` activated in Apache config?

Answer (score 0):

Incorrectly configured .htaccess leads to 500 error. Update you htacces file to fix this error (instead of commenting).

Change

```
IndexIgnore */*
```

to

```
IndexIgnore *
```

Comment: It still gives the 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Can you post full .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

First you need the `autoindex_module` activated in Apache config and of course `rewrite_module` if you are doing this in a .htaccess file rather than a Virtual Host.

Also in the `IndexIgnore [file]` syntax `file` is a shell-style wildcard expression or full filename. `*/*` does not look valid to me.

So try something simple to provide it like

```
IndexIgnore *.xxx
```

If that does not cause a 500 error, then the solution is as simple as using a valid file mask for the parameter.